# Mysqldump slow after upgrade to mysql8

Tags: mysql, database, upgrade

My earlier verison mysql 5.7.20, all databases structure backup takes 10 minutes.
After upgrade to mysql 8.0.11 structure backups take 51 hours.
Its huge time for structure backup.
Can anyone help what i missing?

Comment: No idea might be a configuration issue? Which table engines are you trying to back up? I believe this question is better asked on https://dba.stackexchange.com/ so iam voteclosing this question to be offtopic for stackoverflow.

Comment: Configuration settings are proper.because when i am creating new schema and dump fresh data in it then it is working properly.even csv import is very fast.only problem with mysqldump.and in processlist there are so many process continues running in checking permission state.if we kill that process then it will generate again and shown continuesly.

Comment: Post it on MySQL forum as a bug?

Comment: No i have not post it as bug.

Comment: When i am seen information_schema.tables system table in it i found view error. employee.emp_view is not a base table found in so many rows of table_comment column.why is it so??

Comment: It's a legitimate question but probably off topic here and certainly un-answerable with the details you've provided.  We know nothing about your database(s), operating system, method of upgrade, etc.  it sounds like something got corrupted somewhere along the way and only advice I can offer is to try a clean install and rebuild/import your dumps.  good luck

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using tablespaces, it might help to use mysqldump's option "--no-tablespaces", that will speed it up considerably if you have many tables.

See also: https://bugs.launchpad.net/percona-server/+bug/1589334/comments/2